# передача данных из одного запроса в другой

Tags: javascript, jquery

Выводит: "Результат1: 35; результат2: 38,"
         "Результат1: 22; результат2: 22, "
         " итого: 73"
         " итого: 44"

Надо: "Результат1: 35; результат2: 38, итого: 73"
      "Результат1: 22; результат2: 22, итого: 44"

Пытался примостить promise. Не получилось. Вот код:

```
$("#a").load('a.php',{x:x},function(data){
  num1 = data.substr(data.indexOf(''),8);
  for(var i=1; i <= num1; i++){
    num2 = data.substr(data.indexOf(''),10);
    num3 = data.substr(data.indexOf(''),10);
    num4 = data.substr(data.indexOf(''),10);
    $("#b").append("Результат1: "+num2+"; результат2: "+num3+",");

    $("#a").load('c.php',{num4:num4},function(data){
      $("#b").append(" итого: "+func(data));
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: можно конечно num2 и num3 отправить  вместе с num4 и вывести внутри второго запроса. Но может есть лучше вариант?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, суть в том, что у вас цикл прокручивается быстрее, чем приходит ответ с *c.php*.

Решить это можно следующим способом

```js
$("#a").load('a.php', {
  x: x
}, function (data) {
  num1 = data.substr(data.indexOf(''), 8);
  
  for (var i = 1; i <= num1; i++) {
    $("#a").load('c.php', {
      num2: num2,
      num3: num3,
      num4: num4
    }, function (data) {
      $("#b").append("Результат1: " + num2 + "; результат2: " + num3 + ", итого: " + func(data));
    });
  };
});
```

По другому, можно вычислять "итого" в JS, а не отправлять ещё один запрос

Comment: Предложенный вариант я рассматривал выше " 
можно конечно num2 и num3 отправить вместе с num4...". Я так пока и сделал. На второй ответ "по другому вычислить "итого": при первом запросе определяется переменная num4 по которой осуществляется поиск во втором запросе. Пробовал в PHP это сделать. Там тоже получается запрос в запросе.